# Understanding Template meta programming concepts & terminology

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I have tried all source available on net and books not able to understand the concepts and syntax for the template.

```
template <int N>
struct Factorial 
{
    enum { value = N * Factorial<N - 1>::value };
};

template <>
struct Factorial<0> 
{
    enum { value = 1 };
};

// Factorial<4>::value == 24
// Factorial<0>::value == 1
void foo()
{
    int x = Factorial<4>::value; // == 24
    int y = Factorial<0>::value; // == 1
}
```

what is the `value` which associate with `Factorial<4>::value`
why we need `enum` here. 
what is the difference between `struct Factorial<0>` and `struct Factorial`, why if I am  declaring like `struct Factorial<4>`, why its giving error?

Comment: All sources? Really? Pardon my skepticism, but experience taught me that whenever someone says that it means they tried one or two terribly written blog posts and called it quits. Can you elaborate on what you tried? Did you read [this documentation from boost](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/libs/mpl/doc/tutorial/tutorial-metafunctions.html)? Or the book it was extracted from, *"C++ Template Metaprogramming"*?

Comment: What error is "it" giving you when you try to declare `struct Factorial<4>`? How are you trying to declare that? *Why* are you trying to declare that? (More insight into your current conceptions and misconceptions regarding templates would increase the chances of you getting an answer that helps.)

Comment: If you're looking for a comprehensive introduction to templates, that's probably too broad a question for SO. However, if you focus on a single issue (like the error), that *might* make your question on-topic.

Comment: One question at a time, and please include the exact error messages you got within the question

Answer (score 2):

> what is the `value` which associate with `Factorial<4>::value`

It's an member of an anonymous `enum`, and it's initialised from a calculation. To find it's value, the compiler has to know `Factorial<3>::value`, which requires `Factorial<2>::value`, which requires `Factorial<1>::value`, which requires `Factorial<0>::value`.

> what is the difference between `struct Factorial<0>` and `struct Factorial`

`template <> struct Factorial<0>` is a [specialisation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization) of the base `template <int N> struct Factorial`, which only applies when the `int` template parameter is `0`. Providing it here stops the infinite regress that would otherwise occur.

Comment: will it work only for enum, i mean instead of "value" which is a enum can we make it some othertype

Comment: It doesn't *have to be* `enum`, but that's common and well understood. It could be `static const int value = N * Factorial<N - 1>::value`, or `static constexpr int value = N * Factorial<N - 1>::value`